# Accumulate scores

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in the form below.  Each object represents the result of a soccer game.  The actual array contains far more records than what I have here.  In each game, the team (home or away) that has the highest corresponding score gets 3 points and the team with the lowest score gets 0 points.  If the scores are the same, each team gets 1 point.  I want to create logic that aggregates the points for each unique team whether they are home or away.  I would like to see different types of options (newer syntax, etc), but especially a vanilla javascript solution.

I plan to work through it as well, but I'm struggling to come up with anything succinct.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4824f3a469a068edc875e2"),
    "homeTeam" : "Team1",
    "homeScore" : 2,
    "awayTeam" : "Team2",
    "awayScore" : 1,
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4824f3a469a068edc894e9"),
    "homeTeam" : "Team2",
    "homeScore" : 2,
    "awayTeam" : "Team3",
    "awayScore" : 1,
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4824f3a469a068edc554e7"),
    "homeTeam" : "Team4",
    "homeScore" : 1,
    "awayTeam" : "Team5",
    "awayScore" : 1,
}]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  Also, you're missing a comma after the first object.  I assume that is a typo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce .... it's the very first result when you google "javascript accumulate"

Comment: "I plan to work through it as well, but I'm struggling to come up with anything succinct."  That's really not how SO works.  This isn't a code writing service.  Come up with something, and when you have trouble with it, we can help you get it working.

Comment: Thank you Amy,  I'll come back to you when I have something and I'll keep it in mind for next time.  For anyone that did help, I appreciate it.

Comment: George Jempty, I want an object array that has team total points and a couple of other stats, but I will work on that myself once I get on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [{
    "_id" : "5a4824f3a469a068edc875e2",
    "homeTeam" : "Team1",
    "homeScore" : 2,
    "awayTeam" : "Team2",
    "awayScore" : 1,
},
{
    "_id" : "5a4824f3a469a068edc894e9",
    "homeTeam" : "Team2",
    "homeScore" : 2,
    "awayTeam" : "Team3",
    "awayScore" : 1,
},{
    "_id" : "5a4824f3a469a068edc554e7",
    "homeTeam" : "Team4",
    "homeScore" : 1,
    "awayTeam" : "Team5",
    "awayScore" : 1,
}];

var teamStats = {};

var i = 0;
for(;i < data.length; i++) {

    // New Home team
    if(teamStats[data[i].homeTeam] == undefined) {
    teamStats[data[i].homeTeam] = {
        name: data[i].homeTeam,
      score: 0
    }
  }

  // New Away team
  if(teamStats[data[i].awayTeam] == undefined) {
    teamStats[data[i].awayTeam] = {
        name: data[i].awayTeam,
      score: 0
    }
  }

  // Update score
  teamStats[data[i].homeTeam].score += data[i].homeScore;
  teamStats[data[i].awayTeam].score += data[i].awayScore;
}

// teamStats contains a scores of all teams
```

Comment: Thanks David Horak. As Amy suggested I will try to work on this first and use your solution as a reference before I come back and mark it.